# Match previous record after SQL Select

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to build on this code but I don't know how to tackle the 2nd part of this code. In the beginning the code in the SQL it is selected a record's caseid, program, and language from table Intake WHERE assignedto is Null. This is working perfectly fine.

Once a record is selected, I want another code that checks if the selected record's caseid matches the caseid of a PREVIOUS record. This is where I am lost. Here is where I am at:

```
Set db = CurrentDb

strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 IntakeID, caseid, [Program], [language] FROM Intake WHERE assignedto Is Null"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

i = rs!caseid
If DLookup("caseid", "Intake", i) Then

Call GetPreviousWorker
```

I know that I'm not using the DLookup properly, I'm attempting to find a matching record and clearly failing haha. Thank you to anyone who can help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `IntakeId` is the primary key incrementing by 1 in the `Intake` table

so your requriement can achieve as below

```
Set db = CurrentDb

strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 IntakeID, caseid, [Program], [language] FROM Intake WHERE assignedto Is Null"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

 While Not rs!EOF

strSQL = "SELECT IntakeID, caseid, [Program], [language],[other required fields]   
          FROM Intake WHERE IntakeId=" & rs!IntakeID - 1
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

 if rs!caseid = rs1!caseid Then

  do what in this case..update or something..

else //means current record case id is not equal to previous one
 ..
 End IF
 rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking...

```
     if Dlookup("caseid","intake","caseid = " & caseid &  
     " AND Intake <> " & rs.Fields("IntakeID")) then
       ' your Code
     end if
```

Take note that Dlookup only returns the first occurence that matches the criteria...If you have more than 1 previous record then you need another approach

Comment: Thanks John, but where is `& id &` coming from? Did you mean to put `& caseid &`?

Comment: I'm getting an error: Item not found in this collection and when I hover over rs.Fields("IntakeID")) it's showing: `rs.Fields("IntakeID")=<item not found in this collection>`

Comment: I must have the complete table structure...my Dlookup is based on what i see from your code

Comment: Here are the table fields: IntakeID (auto-number Primary Key), LobbyID (text), assignedby (text), assignedto (text), workerid, dateassigned (date), Program (text), ScheduledType (text), appdate (date), CheckedIn (yes/no), caseid (text), lastname (text), firstname (text), language (text), comments (text), status (text), actiondate (date). I hope this is what I meant by table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `DCount` caseid?

```
If DCount("caseid", "Intake", "caseid=" & i) > 1 Then
    Call GetPreviousWorker
    ...
```